# Calculation with big numbers gives different results on Codeforces than locally on Ubuntu

Tags: c++

This was question of Codeforces round 686, link for question is: http://codeforces.com/contest/686/problem/A

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])  
{
    constint n=0; // initially x;
    long int x = 0;
    long int count = 0;
    long int d = 0;
    char ch;
    cin>>n>>x;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        cin>>ch>>d;
        if(ch == '+'){
            x = x + d;
        }
        if(ch == '-'){
            if( d > x){
                count++;
            }
            else if(d == x){
                x = x - d; 
            }
            if(d < x){
                x = x- d;
            }
        }
    }
    cout<<x<<" "<<count<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This gives me wrong answer on codeforces compiler but when I compile it on my Ubuntu system, it works fine!

Gives WA for test case:

```
6 1000000000
+ 1000000000
+ 1000000000
+ 1000000000
+ 1000000000
+ 1000000000
+ 1000000000
```

Output:

```
7000000000 0
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: `long int` is only guaranteed to be `2^32-1`, try using `long long` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Just try to use `long long unsigned int x`.